# Find power series from known radius and center

Tags: sequences-and-series

This one has me pretty confused, spent a lot of time experimenting on Wolfram Alpha.

So given the knowledge that the radius of convergence is $3$ and the center is $2$, I need to find several power series that have different behavior at the endpoints.

For the first power series, it must converge at both endpoints. Which means I need a $C_n$ such that both $(-1)^nC_n$ and $(-5)^nC_n$ are convergent series. After trying a bunch of different rational functions in terms of $n$, I can't seem to get a function which converges itself and also makes the series converge.

Does anyone have some tips to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You won't find a **rational** function whose Taylor series converges at an endpoint of the interval of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for $c(n)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c(n) (x-2)^n$ has radius of convergence $3$ and convergence at both endpoints. Convergence at the right endpoint $5$ is saying $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c(n) (5-2)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c(n) 3^n$ converges. Convergence at the left endpoint $-1$ is saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c(n) (-1-2)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c(n) (-3)^n$ converges.

Note that a sufficient condition for the alternating series to converge is that $c(n) \geq 0$ is decreasing to $0$. Great, now we just need to make the right endpoint converge, but not too quickly. How about taking $c(n) = 3^{-n} b(n)$. What would a good choice of $b(n)$ be? How about $b(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$?

Then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c(n) 3^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$$ but
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n 3^{-n}\frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{r}{3}\right)^n\frac{1}{n^2} = \infty
$$
for any $r>3$ since the terms don't even go to $0$. It follows that the radius of convergence is exactly $3$.

Comment: Ahh thank you, that definitely helped me correct several things I was doing wrong. If I wanted to make one end diverge and another converge, then, would I just make bn alternating?

Comment: Well one of the series is already alternating $(-3)^n$, remember? So taking $b(n)$ alternating will just switch the $3^n$ and $(-3)^n$ series, not accomplishing anything for you. What you need to do is change the rate of convergence. Try taking $b(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ and see what happens.

Comment: Oh right, because then I'm left (after the multiplication) with a divergent p-series! Thank you!

Comment: Wait, actually I got that for x=-1, the resulting series is (-1)^n*(1/n) which diverges by the alternating series test, and x=5 gives just the series (1/n), which is a divergent p-series. So doesn't cn = 3^(-n)*(1/n) make both endpoints diverge?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ **converges** by the alternating series test.

Comment: Yup, you're right, my bad. Last step is figuring out how to make that end diverge and the other converge, which I'll try and work out here.

Comment: Which, as it turns out, was as simple as changing the sign.